# Using WebKit (Safari compatible) in delphi to simulate iPhone mobile

Tags: iphone, delphi, safari, webkit, delphi-5

Has anyone successfully used [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org) in Delphi?

> WebKit is an open source web browser engine. WebKit is also the name of the Mac OS X system framework version of the engine that's used by **Safari**, Dashboard, Mail, and many other OS X applications.

I want to create an iPhone/iPad Mobile Simulator same as in [electricplum](http://www.electricplum.com/). (I have tried the [FREE version](http://www.electricsimulator.com/electric_simulator_lite_4a.zip) - seems like it also uses Adobe AIR).

With [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) browser we have the most accurate preview results for iPhone mobile sites. so I would like to embed the WebKit (that is used by Safari) in my application, so my customers can have a reliable preview of their mobile web sites.

I have searched the web, but could not find a working code. (The best I could find was [this](http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1354), but it's not working).

---

The 3 main problems with Delphi Chromium Embedded suggested in the answers are that:

- It does not support D5
- I can overcome the fact that there is no support for D5 (creating the component with D7 in a separate process or DLL) But, It is **very unstable**! I have tested it with D7: Random access violations.
- It does not render HTML pages with div layout/HTML5 same as Safari does (or electricplum - "Electric Mobile Simulator").

Comment: WARNING: The provided link to the Safari code in the board message of bsalsa.com is reported as dangerous (the link to _http://www.simail.si/download/Delphi_Webkit.7z). DON'T DOWNLOAD IT!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [DelphiChromiumEmbedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).  It's not Safari, but it is Webkit based at least...

Comment: @kobik ChromiumEmbedded is pretty much your best bet... however I see you have a D5 tag there... not sure if you'll be able to use it without some changes...

Comment: I have tested Chromium. as I thought, it is based on Google chrome engine so it renders the HTML like chrome (which is not what I want) and does not use [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/). It is also very unstable.

Comment: @kobik: I was under the impression that Chrome *did* use Webkit.  And Wikipedia says it does...

Comment: @MasonWheeler As I understand it, Chrome uses WebCore (part of WebKit), but doesn't use WebKit's JavaScript engine, having replaced JavaScriptCore with V8.

Comment: chrome basically is webkit =)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since I have to accept one. maybe in the future Chromium will be stable...

Answer (score 3):

The reliability of that is not going to be very good. In a corporate environment you might want to just put a mac on the network with the iPad/iPhone simulator from xcode, and script it to open your site and take screenshots.

Or even write a iOS program to open a webkit view with your site, and just put an iPad on the network.

- [Taking a screenshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html)
- [Open a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173053/ios-button-to-webpage-with-uiwebview)
- [Running in the background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)
- [Sending mail directly through smtp](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)

And take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360552/automate-screenshots-on-iphone-simulator/1579182#1579182)

You might want to consider how much work a delphi webkit is going to be compared to just buying a mac. The upgrade cycle is going to be painful whatever route you take, but quality is going to be much better with the mac/iPad.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned, Safari on Windows gives us  *very good* results. In fact our design team is using ["Electric Mobile Simulator"](http://www.electricplum.com/) with great success. But I want to embed that inside our product.

Comment: +1 BTW. That gave me an interesting idea... maybe there are already exists reliable web-services based on iOS, that will get an input of the URL, and return a PDF...

Comment: comment to @Self: using a screenshot is problematic, because the screenshot is not responsive. meaning I can't actually navigate and actually see transpositions effects for example.

Comment: On a mac/pc you could use vnc/ichat/skype/remote desktop or so to capture screen semi-live. If your connection is good enough (and the machine fast enough) you should be able to have no dropped frames